# how to get the current base URL for the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

so iam running two localhosts one for the backend and the other front

I want something like

```
window.locatin.origin
```

but this gives me the web url

i need the port of the backend localhost

if there's way please tell me

Comment: Can you add details about how your back-end and front-end work together? I see you tagged `axios`, so is your back-end just an API you want to send request to? Or does the back-end serve your front-end too in a public folder for example?